# Update with multiple CASE

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
BEGIN TRAN    
UPDATE SubUnitAreas  
        SET SA.GIA = CASE TEMP.[Rentable SF] WHEN (TEMP.[Useable SF] <= 0  AND TEMP.[Rentable SF] <= 0) THEN  TEMP.[Rentable SF] ELSE END,   
        SA.GIAMeas = 1,   
        SA.NIA = CASE TEMP.[Useable SF] WHEN (TEMP.[Useable SF] <= 0  AND TEMP.[Rentable SF] <= 0) THEN  TEMP.[Useable SF] ELSE END,   
        SA.NIAMeas = 1  
    FROM SubUnitAreas SA  
        INNER JOIN SubUnit SU ON SA.SubUnitKey = SU.SubUnitKey  
        INNER JOIN TRT_140317_SubUnitAreas TEMP ON TEMP.[LEASE ID] = SU.TenureID  
    WHERE SA.SubUnitKey = SU.SubUnitKey AND SU.TenureID NOT IN ('DUB008')  
ROLLBACK TRAN
```

Comment: Do you have a question for us?

Comment: Can i use multiple conditions within in a WHEN clause under the CASE, to UPDATE multiple columns. I am missing something guide me through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly, but you have a syntax error in your code, as you did not supply a value in the ELSE-case. Furthermore, if you want to use a logical expression after every WHEN-keyword, you should not supply a value after the CASE-keyword. If you want to leave a column to its original value, in case none of the conditions are satisfied, just do this:

```
UPDATE SubUnitAreas SET 
    SA.GIA = CASE WHEN <<logical expression>> THEN TEMP.[Rentable SF] ELSE SA.GIA END,
    SA.GIAMeas = 1,
    ...
```

Comment: In ELSE Case i want to do nothing, i mean to say can i provide SA.GIA only?

Comment: Yes, if you `SET SA.GIA = SA.GIA` then nothing happens and the column will retain its original value. I am not quite sure if triggers will still fire, however. Maybe someone else can answer that. However, to be sure to avoid firing triggers (if you have any), you could add your logical expressions `OR`'ed together in the WHERE-part of your query.

Comment: Thank You for the immediate response DAN:)

Comment: No problem. If my answer helped you, consider marking it as the answer for your question, so that others can see that the solution worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to give an ELSE <>

BEGIN TRAN
UPDATE SA
    SET SA.GIA = CASE WHEN (TEMP.[Useable SF] <= 0  AND TEMP.[Rentable SF] <= 0) THEN  TEMP.[Rentable SF] ELSE SA.GIA END, 
        SA.GIAMeas = 1, 
        SA.NIA = CASE WHEN (TEMP.[Useable SF] <= 0  AND TEMP.[Rentable SF] <= 0) THEN  TEMP.[Useable SF] ELSE SA.NIA END, 
        SA.NIAMeas = 1
    FROM SubUnitAreas SA
        INNER JOIN SubUnit SU ON SA.SubUnitKey = SU.SubUnitKey
        INNER JOIN TRT_140317_SubUnitAreas TEMP ON TEMP.[LEASE ID] = SU.TenureID
    WHERE SA.SubUnitKey = SU.SubUnitKey AND SU.TenureID NOT IN ('DUB008', 'MT001')
ROLLBACK TRAN